# can one use getPackageManager in a function which doesn't have a context?

Tags: android

This question is a little bit hard to ask:

With a Timer, a method is started each 5 seconds, and inside this function I need to know what activities are actually running so I write :

```
public class ProcessesCheck extends TimerTask {

@Override
public void run() {
   Log.w("hello", "my name is Nicolas".concat( String.valueOf( SystemClock.uptimeMillis() )));
   Context.getPackageManager();
       etc.....
}
```

}

the run method is run each 5 seconds.

But the problem is that I don't have Context, and I even can't instantiate a my_context object, in order to get the method getPackageManager.

So the line :'Context.getPackageManager();' have an error!

Does someone know how to launch getPackageManager in the method "run"?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time it's just `getPackageManager()` that you want.  It's never `Context.getPackageManager()`, since it isn't a static method.

It looks like your `ProcessesCheck` is a standalone class, so you'll need to make a valid context object available to this code, perhaps by passing one in via the constructor. If you name it `context`, then you'd have `context.getPackageManager()`.

Comment: The problem is that I even can't instance Context as it's abstract.

Comment: @NicolasBourdon Yes, that's what I mean by "making a valid context object available to it by passing one in via the constructor". Making your class an inner class of your Service is another good way to do accomplish that, as you've apparently done.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did that, and it seems to work well.

```
public class Automated_launcher_service extends Service {

Context my_service = this;

private TimerTask my_TimerTask = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        Log.w("hello", "my name is Nicolas" + String.valueOf( SystemClock.uptimeMillis() ) );
        Object my_packages = my_service.getPackageManager();
        Log.w("hello", "my name is Nicolas" + String.valueOf(my_packages));
    }
};


int i = 0;


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Timer my_timer = new Timer("automated launchemy loop",true);
    if(i==0){
        i=1;
        my_timer.schedule(my_TimerTask, 0, 5000);
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

}
```